# code runs in terminal, but not in text file

Tags: python-2.7

I have yet another question,
All the scripts that i have made for python so far i have used a text editor and written to a text file .py made it executable and then made a widget on my desktop to run the file.
That way i can make changes to the code, save and click my widget to view changes.

I have been trawling the internet trying to find a way to get a script I'm working on to work properly and i have noticed a lot of the examples don't work the way i have been doing things, but if i enter the same code into a python shell it works just fine.

I'm not sure if that makes sense so heres an example.
If i open up a python terminal and type this code it works just fine and i get a window pop up with a list of numbers.

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

listbox = Listbox(root)
listbox.pack()

for i in range(20):
    listbox.insert(END, str(i))
mainloop()
```

On the other hand if i take the same code and save it to a text file .py make it executable then try and run it nothing will happen.

It doesn't make sense to me, surely its exactly the same thing, or am i missing out on something here??
I can't get used to using python terminal so I just use the text editor route

I'm using Python 2.7.3 if that helps, many thanks

Comment: _"I have used a text editor and written to a text file .py, made it executable, and then made a widget on my desktop to run the file."_ What do you mean by "made it executable" and "made a widget"? Are you doing something other than entering "python myscript.py" into the terminal?

Comment: Yes i have been doing something else but i have now started using "python myscript.py" as you suggested as it gives better information when i get errors, so thanks for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using Linux from the question. Have you tried adding `#!/usr/bin/python` to the top of the file so that your OS knows what program to use?

Comment: Thank you that fixed it straight away, Yes using kali linux. I have seen #!/usr/bin/python in scripts before but never knew what it did, i just assumed because it was hashed out it didn't do anything. It makes sense now you have explained. Thank you @ChrisProsser